# Is the function continuous/differentiable at (0, 0)?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> $f(a, b) = (ba)^{2/3}$ at $(0, 0)$

The linear approximation is $L(a, b) = f(0,0) + f_a(0,0)(a) + f_b(0,0)(b)$

$f_a(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0 = f_b(0,0)$ so $L(a, b) = 0$

So we also have

$\lim_{(a, b) \to (0, 0)} \frac{(ab)^{2/3}}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} = 0$

So is the function differentiable and continuous at (0, 0)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and therefore continuous at $(0,0)$.